# Use double stemming for two languages in R

Tags: r, tm, stemming

In my corpus there are two languages russian and english.

```
Hello, how are you
Привет, как дела
```

Can i use  double stemming for two languages
somthing like this

```
tw.corpus <- tm_map(tw.corpus,stemDocument,  c("russian","english"))
```

Or it is need another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stemDocument` only takes into account the first argument of your vector of languages. Your present code will only stem Russian (and not English).

To perform a double stemming, you simply need to perform the stemming twice (one per language).

```
tw.corpus <- tm_map(tw.corpus,stemDocument,  c("russian"))
tw.corpus <- tm_map(tw.corpus,stemDocument,  c("english"))
```